# I am trying to create an auto login for a site on firefox using python, but I keep getting this error for clicking the button, please help me out

Tags: python, selenium

here is the code(it is working all fine till the entry of username and password but gives error for clicking the "submit"/"play" button ):-

```
from selenium import webdriver # Used to import the driver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
#from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import time
#mouse = Controller()
def bot(usr,pas):
    
    br=webdriver.Firefox() 
    br.get("https://tankionline.com/play/")
    time.sleep(10)
    br.find_element_by_link_text("Sign in").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    #user=br.find_element_by_css_selector("username")
    username = br.find_element_by_id("username")
    username.send_keys(usr)
    password=br.find_element_by_id("password")
    password.send_keys(pas)
    ActionChains(webdriver).click("<span>Play </span>").perform()
    
#main driver code
bot("Ricochet_Master","********")
```

AND HERE IS THE ERROr(is there an alternative to the button auto click to avoid this error?):-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aaryan/selenium auto login 2.py", line 24, in <module>
    bot("Ricochet_Master","********")
  File "/home/aaryan/selenium auto login 2.py", line 20, in bot
    ActionChains(webdriver).click("<span>Play </span>").perform()
  File "/home/aaryan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 72, in __init__
    if self._driver.w3c:
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'w3c'
```

Comment: ActionChains() requires the driver parameter. Try changing to ActionChains(driver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that you need move to element at all.

All you need is a webdriver wait. Cause when you fill username and password we see that the Play button is enabled.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "username"))).send_keys('username')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password"))).send_keys('password')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-style='LoginComponentStyle-buttonPlay']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: But what to write for clicking the link text "Sign in" using EC(expected conditions)?

Comment: wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "TEXT here")))

Comment: You can refer this official site : https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `ActionChains()` constructor requires you to pass a Driver as an argument:
`ActionChains(br).click...` Will do the job.

Following your comment:
You invoked `ActionChains(br).move_to()` the  function `move_to` expects a `WebElement` parameter.
So do the following:

```
element = driver.find_element(...)
ActionChains(br).move_to(element)
```

You will need to provide a valid locator for the element.

Comment: now the error is:
  File "/home/aaryan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 102, in click
    self.move_to_element(on_element)
  File "/home/aaryan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 273, in move_to_element
    self.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_to(to_element)
 File "/home/aaryan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/actions/pointer_actions.py", line 42, in move_to
   raise AttributeError("move_to requires a WebElement")
AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement